# Clone behavior diffent in REPL vs script

Tags: iolanguage

I have this piece of code that behaves differently in the io REPL vs running it as a script (i.e. `io matrix_clone_test.io`). 
To be specific:

- in the REPL, matrix1 and matrix2 point to different objects (different ids: Matrix_0x504b80, Matrix_0x42edd0)
- when executing the script, matrix1 and matrix2 point to the same object (same ids: Matrix_0x40f210, Matrix_0x40f210)

I was expecting in both cases to see different objects resulting from `Matrix clone`. What am I missing?

**Code snippet**

```
Matrix := Object clone
matrix1 := Matrix clone
matrix2 := Matrix clone
matrix1 proto println
matrix2 proto println
```

**Console output**

```
Io> Matrix := Object clone
==>  Matrix_0x739da0:
  type             = "Matrix"

Io> matrix1 := Matrix clone
==>  Matrix_0x504b80:

Io> matrix2 := Matrix clone
==>  Matrix_0x42edd0:
[println code excluded for brevity]
```

**Script execution**

```
 Matrix_0x40f210:
  type             = "Matrix"

 Matrix_0x40f210:
  type             = "Matrix"
```

Comment: Going to need some more information here; when I run your exact code in my Io interpreter, I get the expected result. Prints, then returns the string it printed for both println calls. If you're referring to the `0x123456` bits, those will always be different for different runs of the interpreter (i.e., REPL vs code, or REPL vs REPL, or code vs code)

Comment: yes @jer I'm referring to the bits Matrix_0x40f210. I understand that for REPL vs code they're going to be different. My question is why are they not different where I run the code 'matrix1 proto println; matrix2 proto println'